# Vue.js router-link params expected to be defined but getting browser error "missing param for named route <route_name>: expected <param> to be defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Hi I'm trying to use a Vue.js `router-link` to pass a parameter dynamically into a component.  I'm getting a browser error that says that the parameter is not defined, even though the router URL is being displayed correctly, with the parameter.  The component is also rendered, but the data does not seem to be accessible in the component as a property or data element.

Here is my table with router-link:

```
<sui-table-row v-for="(player, i) in allPlayers" :key="i">
      <sui-table-cell>{{player.league}}{{i+1}}</sui-table-cell>
      <sui-table-cell>{{ player.player1 }}&{{player.player2}}</sui-table-cell>
      <sui-table-cell selectable v-for="(week, j) in allDates" :key="j">
           <router-link :to="{ name: 'addWeek', params: {team1: player._id } }">
          {{player.schedule[j]}}
           </router-link>
    </sui-table-cell>
</sui-table-row>
```

Routes.js

```
import AddWeek from '@/views/admin/addWeek.vue';

const routes = [{      
    path: '/ncl-schedule/addWeek/:team1',      
    name: 'addWeek',      
    component: AddWeek    
  }]
export default routes
```

Two issues I'm having here:

1: Chrome is throwing the following error:

> [vue-router] missing param for named route "addWeek": Expected "team1" to be defined

This is odd because I get the team id passed as the param on the route, and it brings me to the `AddWeek` component as I'd expect.

> http://localhost:8080/ncl-schedule/addWeek/5e6bc31785aa8e5ab4575d80

2: I can't get the data as a property or data element in the component, however.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that player `_id` isn't ready when the component is first rendered, maybe it's async data.  Try a `v-if` on your link:

```html
<router-link v-if="player && player._id" :to="{ name: 'addWeek', params: {team1: player._id } }">
```

Params are accessed at `this.$route.params` in the target component.  You *can* automatically convert those to props if you prefer, by defining your route with the `props: true` option:

```js
const routes = [{      
  path: '/ncl-schedule/addWeek/:team1',      
  name: 'addWeek',      
  component: AddWeek,
  props: true    
}]
```

You need to also create the `team1` prop in `addWeek`.

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Please checkmark this answer and this will help other people as well. You can do so [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png).  Or let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

[Click Schedule Link Here to View Example](https://www.adamhelm.com)

With regard to the initial Chrome error, Dan was correct that the data was async and therefore not rendered upon initial load.  This is resolved now in this solution.

I ultimately wanted multiple parameters to be passed in from the component. In order to accomplish this I used "query" opposed to "params", in the "router-link".  The rest of the code block is included for clarification of the parameters being passed.

**Parent Component:**

```
<sui-table-row v-for="(players, i) in allPlayers" :key="i">
  <sui-table-cell>{{players.league}}{{players.teamNumber}}</sui-table-cell>
  <sui-table-cell>{{ players.player1 }}&{{players.player2}}</sui-table-cell>
  <sui-table-cell selectable v-for="(week, j) in allDates" :key="j">

    **<router-link :to="{ name: 'addWeek', query: {selectedTeam: players, week: week.weekId, match: players.schedule[j] } }">
      {{players.schedule[j]}}
    </router-link>**

  </sui-table-cell>
</sui-table-row>
```

**routes.js**

```
const routes = [{      
        path: '/schedule/addWeek',      
        props(route) {
          return route.query || {}
        },
        name: 'addWeek',      
        component: AddWeek    
    }]
```

Finally within the component I wanted to access the data I retrieved them from the route within the mounted hook as follows:

**Consuming Component:**

```
   async mounted() {
        // this is the team in the players field who's week's matches were chosen.
        this.selectedTeam = this.$route.query.selectedTeam
        // teams clicked on
        this.teamsPlayed = this.$route.query.match
        // this is the week the matches take place - intersection of selectedTeam, date
        this.schedule.weekId = this.$route.query.week
        }
```